# Multiple apps in Ruby Padrino: How to name models?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, models, padrino

I have a Padrino project, that consists of multiple apps. For example:

- Website (**Models: Site, Page**)
- Blog (**Models: Post, Comment**)
- Shop (**Models: Category, Product, Order**)
- Tracking (**Models: Visitor, Content**)

Putting all models unmodified into one directory seems to me like a mess. So I thought of namespacing them like:

- Website (**Models: Site, SitePage**)
- Blog (**Models: BlogPost, BlogComment**)
- Shop (**Models: ShopCategory, ShopProduct, ShopOrder**)
- Tracking (**Models: TrackingVisitor, TrackingContent**)

But this looks very strange and produces a lot of extra typing.

What do you think? Is it good style to ignore namespacing and hope not to run into a naming conflict (e.g. "Category" model for Blog app => Error) or should I prepend the apps name to each model?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers Marc

Answer (score 1):

I use a module as namespace ie:

```
module BlogModels
  class Category
  end
end
```

and works quite well example with dm because I've namespaced `table_name`, btw your way `BlogCategory` is also fine to me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast answer. I'm using mongoid. Putting my models into modules for namespacing sounds great, but this does not affect MongoDB collection naming and I have to specify them manually. So I thought of applying the Namespace to the model name instead of putting it into a module. Don't you think it is inconsitent to have a shop model called "Category" and a blog model "BlogCategory"?

Answer (score 0):

I found a reasonable way to namespace the models in Mongoid and keep the overhead small.

I name the models like this: BlogPost, BlogComment, BlogCategory

And in the model I make use of class_name and inverse_of:

```
class BlogPost

  include Mongoid::Document

  # ... lots of stuff ommitted

  has_many :comments, class_name: 'BlogComment', inverse_of: :post
end

class BlogComment

  include Mongoid::Document

  # ... lots of stuff ommitted

  belongs_to :post, class_name: 'BlogPost', inverse_of: :comments
end
```

And access via:

```
post = BlogPost.first
post.comments.first # get comments

BlogComment.first.post # get related post
```

This keeps the access chain short and is better then:

```
post = BlogPost.first
post.blog_comments.first # get comments

BlogComment.first.blog_post # get related post
```

More details: http://mongoid.org/docs/relations.html